# cleveref: Change value of the word 'and'

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

What have I to do to manipulate the and-conjunction?

I tested all the conjunctions I found in the manual, without success.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{}{}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{\,--\,} % good
% ???:
\newcommand{\crefmiddleconjunction}{ ppp}
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{ qqq}
\newcommand{\crefpairgroupconjunction }{ aaa}
\newcommand{\crefmiddlegroupconjunction}{ bbb}
\newcommand{\creflastgroupconjunction}{ ccc}
%\newcommand{\crefrangepreconjunction }{ ddd}
%\newcommand{\crefrangepostconjunction}{ eee}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{Labeling}
\begin{equation}A \label{eq:1}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}B \label{eq:2}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}C \label{eq:3}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}D \label{eq:4}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}E \label{eq:5}\end{equation}

\section{Referencing}
\cref{eq:1,eq:3,eq:4,eq:5}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah, it is simply   `\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction }{ \& }`.